# UITableView with Two Prototype Cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

***UPDATE- Thanks to Farhad for answering my initial post. At the bottom of this post is a new issue i've encountered regarding automatic dimensioning for dynamic cell height***

I've tried searching for other posts but to no avail.

As the title suggests I want to have my table view show two cells with the second cell being custom.

The first cell will have 4 rows - O.D, Weight, I.D, Grade.

The second cell, the custom cell, will have 8 labels displaying the results from the inputs from the first cell.

I have a reuse identifier for both cells. The first cell i've called "capacitiesCell" and my second cell I've called "cell2"

For my second cell, I have created a new tableViewCell file named "CapacitiesTableViewCell" that has 4 of the 8 labels as outlets.

*SIDE NOTE: For the name of the cells I've just put a generic "Section #, Row #" for now but will change the line of code to `cell.textlabel?.text = capacityID` when I've figured the issue out...assuming that's the correct way to go about this.*

Here is my code thus far:

```
class CapacitiesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

let capacityParameters = ["O.D", "Weight", "I.D", "Grade"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 2
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0 {
        return capacityParameters.count
    } else {
        return 1
    }

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("capacitiesCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    //let capacityID = capacityParameters[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Section \(indexPath.section) Row \(indexPath.row)"

    return cell

    let dimensionAndStrengthCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    // my code goes here
    return dimensionAndStrengthCell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    if section == 0 {
        return "Casing Specification"
    } else {
        return "Dimension & Strength"
    }
}
```

This is my storyboard:
[image]

However when I run the app I get this:
[image]

**CHANGING CELL HEIGHT FOR CELL2**

So in my viewDidLoad I have the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200.0
}
```

I'm trying to have my view look like the screenshot below but the "Strength and Dimension" section cell height is stuck on the default height.
[image]

the new code I've added from Farhad's response is :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // init return type of cell
    var returnCell: UITableViewCell!

    if indexPath.section == 0 { // you can also check for section with section.index
        returnCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("capacitiesCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        //let capacityID = capacityParameters[indexPath.row]
        returnCell.textLabel?.text = "Section \(indexPath.section) Row \(indexPath.row)"

    return returnCell

    } else {

        returnCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200.0

        return returnCell

    }
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    if section == 0 {
        return "Casing Specification"
    } else {
        return "Dimension & Strength"
    }
}
```

Comment: You need an `if/else` statement in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you check at what position you need to enter a new **`row`** or **`section`** with `if/else` statement.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        //Init the Return of Cell Type
        var returnCell: UITableViewCell!

        if index.row == 0 { // You can also check for section index.section
         returnCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("capacitiesCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        //let capacityID = capacityParameters[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Section \(indexPath.section) Row \(indexPath.row)"

        return returnCell

        } else {

        returnCell = //Other cell at other rows or section
        return returnCell

        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Farhad! I will test this out very shortly and let you know the outcome!

Comment: Sure, let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Farhad, your code works! Thanks so much. I now ran into the issue of be unable to use --->self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension and  self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200.0 in my viewDidLoad to adjust the size of my second cell. Any ideas ? I'm sure its something to do with the way my constraints are set up. I'll post an update to my post for you to check

Comment: It could be constraint, but `if/else` has nothing to do with cell hight. let me see your code please.

Comment: Ive updated my post with the code at the bottom of my original post. Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: Your  `self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` & `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200.0` should be in `viewDidLoad()`, , cause you want to let your `UITableView` know what hight the cells should be calculated to before the cells are even loaded. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: I tried it in viewDidLoad but no luck. I'm sure it has something to do with the constraints and the hugging content (from what i gathered googling this issue) i will continue playing with this in the meantime

Comment: Well have Automatic dimension in `viewDidLoad()` that's the right place. Now try to remove the bottom constraint and everything as what it was.

Comment: Farhad thanks for your help. I made some changes to the way i handle my constraints and it's seemed to have worked. Much appreciated for your time!

Comment: No problem, I hope I get check for my answer. :)